# Pipenv failing on non-existant constraint

Tags: python, pip, pipenv

`pipenv install` is throwing this error

```
pipenv.exceptions.ResolutionFailure: ERROR: ERROR: Could not find a version that matches pyjwt<2.0.0,>=1.4.0,>=1.4.2,>=2.0.0,~=1.7.1
```

But when I inspect `pipenv graph` I do not have any dependencies that ask for >=2.0.0. I have 1.7.1 installed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have installed more than python interpreters, that's because you are building virtual environments. So, `pyjwt` version in that interpreter does not meet the requirement causes this error.
`py -3.7 -m pip install numpy` 
like command install the package in a specific version. 
However, this command would not work sometimes. 
it is good if you can go to the interpreter install directory and activate `base` env. then install packages.
in the interpreter folder `Scripts/activate`